# How to introduce "setx" command on CentOS 5.2

Tags: linux, centos

I'm working on a CentOS 5.2 system (I know it's very old, but it's the customer's choice).

I am running a program, which internally performs some `setx` commands, but it seems that `setx` is not understood yet by this platform.

Therefore I was thinking to replace `setx` by `export`, using an `alias`, but now a very stupid issue pops up: see following commands' syntax:

```
setx   : setx   <variable> <value> // watch the space
export : export <variable>=<value> // watch the equal-sign
```

Due to that simple difference in syntax I think I can't use `alias setx export` (at least that's what I think, or can I work around that?).

Does anybody have a simple way to get around this? (for your information, I have already found a workaround, but this is using specific features of my technology, and I'm wondering if there is a general solution)

For clarity: the program I'm trying to run is an automatically generated installer, which consists of shell scripts commands, combined with binaries, coded as decimals (I'm not sure whether or not this is the same as BCD). One of those shell script commands is `setx`, and I would like to know what I need to enter in the terminal (something like `define "setx $1 $2" as "export $1=$2"`), before launching the installer.

Comment: What do you mean by "yet"? By "running a program" you mean "running a shell script"? Are you sure the rest of the shell script will run once you fix this point? Either way, why don't you just use an executable script named `setx` which takes two arguments? -- Additional relevant information would be helpful.

Comment: `setx`?  Are you trying to run a Windows batch file on a Linux system?  Post the contents of what you're running, else the only answers you're going to get are guesses.

Comment: I've updated my post. About the "yet": I meant that `setx` is not implemented in CentOS 5.2, but I assume it is/will be implemented in a higher CentOS version.

Comment: "I assume it is/will be implemented in a higher CentOS version" - why? it is a Windows command. Why do you think someone will implement it in Centos?